# "Percentage of" and "Percentage for"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I want to ask if anyone can explain to me when to use "percentage of" vs "percentage for". Let say you have a pie chart like this:

[image]

I'm thinking you use "for" when you want to describe the figure for one individual thing in the whole, as in:

- "The percentage for ***Australia visitors*** is 40%"

And when you use "of" then you must first refer to the whole thing, and then give an indication that which part of the whole thing you are talking about, like:

- "The percentage of visitors ***from Australia*** is 40%"

Thanks for any kind inputs.

Comment: "The percentage _of_ visitors to NZ who come from Australia is 40%." Having established what you are talking about, you could go on to say "The percentage _for_ the UK is 12%."

Comment: @Kate Bunting. Thanks, Kate. I want to ask if you think my thought here is correct? That when you use "of", you must refer to the whole thing, and then use "of" to specify which part you are talking about.

Comment: Yes, I think so.